# EF Core lookup to diffrent entities based on field value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

In my model, i have entity with field that can join (LookUp) different table basing on value of an other field (Document_Type in my example).

example :
I have PurchaseLine entity it's can have relationship with Item or FixedAsset entities, the field document_type define which entity to relate.
Purchase line entity

```
public class PurchaseLine
{
    public string No { get; set; } 
    public int Document_Type { get; set; }  
    public string Document { get; set; } // it's can be item or fixed asset. 
}
```

Item asset entity

```
public class Item
{
    public string No { get; set; } 
   
    // other fields relating to the item table
}
```

Fixed asset entity

```
public class FixedAsset
{
    public string No { get; set; } 
 
   // other fields relating to the fixed asset table
}
```

In the end user interface I need to list items if document type is equal to 0 and assets if it's equal to 1 and  easily access and do action in the concerning table.
Is it possible to implement such a model using LINQ and inheritance in EF Core ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on how to use EF Core. Here are some links:

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)

[Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx)

To roughly answer your question - you need to add IEnumerables of Item and FixedAsset to your ProductLine model so it can potentially access them.

Then you can do something like:

```
var productLineWithItem = await _context.ProductLine
    .Where(x => x.Document_Type == 1)
    .Include(x => x.Item)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I will try to implement your approach, indeed I am new with EF Core, before I used another ORM (XPO if yout know it)